# "was until recently a puzzle" -----is it still a puzzle or not?

Tags: sentence-structure

> With their clicks, sperm whales can detect a squid less than a foot long more than a mile away, and schools of squid from even farther away. But the way that sperm whales find squid **was until recently a puzzle.**

Based on the bold text, is it still a puzzle or not? How to parse this sentence?

Comment: No, it used to be a puzzle, but it is now known how the prey are detected. "But the way that / sperm whales find squid / was until recently / a puzzle."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some commas or other punctuation could help understanding here. The phrase "until recently" is an extra part that adds information, but can be removed

> But the way that sperm whales find squid was until recently a puzzle.

If you remove that parenthesis you get

> But the way that sperm whales find squid was a puzzle.

The use of the past tense here means that it is no longer a puzzle.  The (until recently) means that this puzzle was solved recently.

Answer (score 1):

> But the way that sperm whales find squid was until recently a puzzle

**Paraphrases**

... the way that sperm whales find squid was a puzzle - until recently.

or

... the way that sperm whales find squid was a puzzle - until a recent time.

---

**Answer**

Every part of the last sentence is in the past. We can *infer* from this that the puzzle is solved .

However, in strict logical terms, it could still be a puzzle. For example:

*But the way that sperm whales find squid was until recently a puzzle. In fact it is still a puzzle but the recent discoveries have brought scientists much closer to a solution. The puzzle is no longer a complete mystery and we can expect a complete solution later this year.*

So, you can see that we can assume the puzzle is solved unless there is a proviso that it isn't.  But, in a court of law, the original sentence would not be enough to *prove* that the puzzle is solved.